# Prove or Disprove Existence of Identity/Inverse Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define an operation $ * $ on $ Z $ by $ x*y = 1 + xy $. Prove or disprove whether we have an identity element and/or inverse elements.

I am in Introduction to Modern Algebra class and I do not know how to start this problem. I can't find any example problems that are similar as well. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check the definition of *identity elements*.

Comment: If there is an identity element then $0=0*i=1$ which is impossible.  No identity, no inverses.

Comment: Please choose an informative title. That means something other than subject tags.

Answer (score 2):

We need an element $e$ such that $x=x*e=e*x\,,\forall x$. When $x=0$, we get $0*e=1+0e=1$ , a contradiction.

Since we don't have $e$, we don't have inverses either.

Comment: One more thing here. Any field (here integers, Z) containing {0} (singleton zero) will always have {0} element as exception as e = x-1/x which is not defined for zero. But if it were Q-{0} (all rational numbers)  then it would have had identity element.